# Can someone pray at the place of another one

Tags: quran, salat, hadith, fiqh

Suppose Ahmad has not pray isha because of traveling on a plane. And Ahmad said that to Ibrahim. And before paying the isha pray, Ahmad died. Can Ibrahim pray at the place of Ahmad. And generally can a person pray at the place of another person.

Comment: Ahmad can pray on the plane while being seated. Alternately, he can pray qadha when he arrives at his destination. And based on his distance of travel he may be able to join the Maghrib and Isha salaats before travelling (Please confirm the last statement with a scholar)

Answer (score 1):

No another person can't allowed to perform someone prayer because everyone have to answer and responsible for his or her own actions. 
And prayer is obligated on every Muslim on a certain period of time so everyone have to perform his own prayer. 
Allah granted us with qaza namaz if you are not able to perform prayer you can perform it later which is called qaza.

Answer (score 1):

No, a one can offer his own prayer because prayer is separately obligatory on each Muslim, and every one have to answer about his own deeds in heaven.